# Create a link to a page in a report exoported in PDF in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pdf

I would like to automatize the creation of a table of content in QGIS, when I use the Reports feature, for exporting reports (like atlas).

The first step is to be able to create a clickable link to a page (of the same PDF File), that would work after the export in PDF.

I tried using HTML `href` method in a HTML item from the header (static page) of the report :

```
[%aggregate( 'Tranche_33e462b3_6946_4431_b21d_3e8f4bea9ff5' ,
          'concatenate',
           to_string('<a href="#' || "Tranche_ID" || '">'  || "Tranche_ID" || '<a>-----<br>'))%]
```

And my target in the section of the report :

```
[% '<h2="'|| "Tranche_ID" || '">' || "Tranche_ID" || '</h2>'%]
```

But after exporting in PDF, the link doesn't work when I click on the link.

Another question : do you know if there is any way to make the Table of Content feature of PDF files working? That would solve the issue.
[image]